# Fast matrix inversion without a package

Tags: python, matrix, matrix-inverse

Assume that I have a square [matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics)) `M`.  Assume that I would like to [invert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix) the matrix `M`.

I am trying to use the the fractions `mpq` class within [gmpy2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gmpy2) as members of my matrix `M`.  If you are not familiar with these fractions, they are functionally similar to python's built-in package [`fractions`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html).  The only problem is, there are no packages that will invert my matrix unless I take them out of fraction form.  I require the numbers and the answers in fraction form.  So I will have to write my own function to invert `M`.

There are known algorithms that I could program, such as [gaussian elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination).  However, performance is an issue, so my question is as follows:

**Is there a computationally fast algorithm that I could use to calculate the inverse of a matrix `M`?**

Comment: Any reasonable fast algorithm to do this would _have_ to be implemented in C, as an extension. Another approach would be to multiply them all by their GCD, or just the product of their denominators, to make the into integers, and use packages with C extensions and much more time put in to optimize. This is `O(n)`, so unless the algorithm to invert is better than `O(n)`, it won't hurt the time complexity.

Comment: Have you looked at sympy? It works great with gmpy2 and matrices: http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/matrices/matrices.html#linear-algebra

Comment: Yes, but sympy's inversion is slower than coding Gaussian elimination by hand.  I can share my code for gaussian elimination with benchmarks.

Answer (score 4):

Is there anything else you know about these matrices? For example, for [symmetric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_matrix) [positive definite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix) matrices, [Cholesky](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition#Python) decomposition allows you to invert faster than the standard Gauss-Jordan method you mentioned.

For general matrix inversions, the [Strassen algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm#Algorithm) will give you a faster result than Gauss-Jordan but slower than Cholesky.

It seems like you want exact results, but if you're fine with approximate inversions, then there are algorithms which approximate the inverse much faster than the previously mentioned algorithms.

However, you might want to ask yourself if you need the entire matrix inverse for your specific application. Depending on what you are doing it might be faster to use another matrix property. In my experience computing the matrix  inverse is an unnecessary step.

I hope that helps!